# Pig - Convert tuple to a string

Tags: tuples, apache-pig

I have a Pig script which returns output as tuples as shown below:

```
(1,2,3)
(a,b,c)
```

I am storing this output into a file and it gets stored with the parenthesis ( and ) as above. I would like to stored the records as below in the file:

```
1,2,3
a,b,c
```

How can I get rid of the parenthesis before using 'STORE INTO' in Pig?

Comment: In the first dump (1,2,3) are the values of a single field or three field ? can you describe the alias and add to the question ?

Comment: The values (1,2,3) are from three fields. That is, 1 is a field1, 2 is field2 and 3 is field3.

Comment: In that case, STORE alias_name INTO 'output_location' USING PigStorage(','); will not save parenthesis ().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DUMP will display the records in a tuple that's the reason why you are seeing 1,2,3 enclosed in parenthesis.()

Ref : http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#pl_dump

Using STORE on the alias will save the values alone.

Ref : http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#pl_store

Comment: Thanks. Did not notice this before.